# How to read flash memory of arduino UNO?

Tags: c#, microcontroller, bootloader

I am new to arduino and basically Computer Science student but interest in embedded systems.
I have little knowledge about programming the chip in ASM or C. I know the basic structure of ARM and AVR MicroControllers. but there is one question in my mind. I searched the net but confused.

My Question is that How to read the whole flash memory of Arduino UNO using Serial Communication in C#?..  The operation should be done using BootLoader.

I have also concepts about ISP, BootLoader, serial programming etc.

My main point is to read/write flash memory of arduino.

Answer (score 0):

That is a really big scope question. I would recommend you search for and review the source code for AVRDUDE. This is the utility used by the Arduino IDE to download code to the AVR micro controller using the boot loader.

You can also review [AVR Open Source Programmer](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2568.pdf) to better understand the requirements.